# Suppressing Objects based on Date - Crystal Reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I have been working on what seemed to a simple date comparison to hide an object until the proper date arrives.

I have trying different variations and each seem NOT to work. I am trying to suppress an object in Crystal Reports until, let's say, August 1 2018. After the specified date, have it display.

**CurrentDate >= #8/1/2018#**

**ToText(CurrentDate) >= "8/1/2018"**

The reasoning I have to change labels soon and rather manually go back in later (I have a ton of labels) figured I'd do what seemed a simple date comparison and switch.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: instead of supressing, Can you filter?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out;

*if (CurrentDate) >= #8/1/2018# AND (@TrueFalse Field) = false then false*

*if (CurrentDate) >= #8/1/2018# AND (@TrueFalse Field) = true then true*

*else true*

Worked like a charm.

Thanks,
Gary